# What are scattering losses?

Tags: spectroscopy

In UV spectroscopy, when a beam of light is shone into solution, what is scattering loss during this process?

Answer (score 4):

Scattering is the redirection of the 'beam' of light, as is illustrated in the diagram below:

[image]

*Source: [University of Wisconsin](http://cimss.ssec.wisc.edu/wxwise/class/optics.html)*

The description from the document [Fundamentals of modern
UV-visible spectroscopy](http://www.chem.agilent.com/library/slidepresentation/public/present.pdf) (Figure 46) states that

> Scattering causes an apparent absorbance because less light
>   reaches the detector

They also detail two main types of scattering in UV spectroscopy (Figure 47):

> • [Rayleigh scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Rayleigh_scattering): Particles small relative to wavelength
>   • [Tyndall scattering](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Physical_Properties_of_Matter/Solutions_and_Mixtures/Colloid/Tyndall_Effect): Particles large relative to wavelength